# NoReverseMatch at /course/ Reverse for 'course_detail' not found. 'course_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to return all courses from the database to my course url and i got this error

NoReverseMatch at /course/

Reverse for 'course_detail' not found. 'course_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

here is my code

```
class Courses(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='courses', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    cover = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="courses_cover/")
    slug = models.SlugField()

    # Courses content
    content_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    content_file = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)

    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('courses:course_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])

    def price_display(self):
        return "{0:.2f}".format (self.price / 100)
```

code for the views.py

```
def course_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    courses = Courses.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        courses = courses.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,'courses/content/list.html', {'category': category, 'categories': categories, 'courses': courses})

def course_detail(request, id, slug):
    course = get_object_or_404(Courses, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    return render(request, 'courses/content/detail.html', {'course': course})
```

code for the course urls

```
app_name = "courses"
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.course_list, name='course_list'),
```

Comment: You don't have a `course_detail` path/view in your urls?

Comment: Thanks this works... i forget to add the path for the course_detail

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your `namespace` in your main `urls.py`? Or have you declared `course` where it should have been `courses` plural?

```
path('courses/', include('courses.urls', namespace='courses')),
```

Comment: Here is my code for the urls path   path('course/', include('courses.urls', namespace='courses')),

Comment: @moses-eyime-akoji What is in your `urlpatterns` for your `course_detail` url because it's not showing in your question. Your problem seems to stem from `get_absolute_url` in your model and Django not being able to reverse your course_detail url.